Get subset of dataframe following a condition from a dictionary
I am trying to find instances of where three columns may exceed some number that is stored in a dictionary. I know this code works, but I think there is a better more pythonic way of doing this.
l = []
for index, row in df_usage.iterrows():
    item_id = row['item_id']
    try:
        if (
            row['start_count'] > historical_orders_dict[item_id]
            or row['end_count'] > historical_orders_dict[item_id]
            or row['received_total'] > historical_orders_dict[item_id]
        ):
            l.append(df_usage.loc[[index], :])
    except:
        pass
df_too_many_consuables = pd.concat(l).reset_index(drop=True)
df_too_many_consuables.shape

Here is an example
historical_orders_dict = {
    '10346': 28644.99,
    '10877': 28979.99,
    '10695': 6200.0,
    '70020': 1960.0,
    '40265': 57300.0,
    '91524': 9750.0,
    '60022': 200.0,
    '10210': 156.0,
    '11040': 49350.0}

data = {
    'item_id': ['10346', '10877', '10695', '70020', '40265', '91524',
                '60022', '10210','11040'],
    'start_count': [100000000, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'end_count': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    'received_total': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 46, 45, 34]}
df_usage = pd.DataFrame(data=data)


Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

@ouroboros1 And for specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples

edited, thanks all

BTW, a bare except is bad practice and in this case covers up the NameError that should have happened. Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like except ValueError.

Okay, cleaned now

Regarding "pythonic", there are some things you could improve here, but unrelated to Pandas. You could ask on [codereview.se] if you want, but read their their How to Ask page first since they work differently.

Related: How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame? Excerpts from answers: "In many cases, iterating manually over the rows is not needed [...] Look for a vectorized solution: many operations can be performed using built-in methods or NumPy functions, (boolean) indexing, ..." and "Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern [...] A good number of basic operations and computations are "vectorised" by pandas. This includes arithmetic, comparisons, [...]"

Here's one approach:
item_map = df_usage['item_id'].map(historical_orders_dict)

mask = (df_usage[['start_count', 'end_count', 'received_total']]
        .gt(item_map, axis=0)
        .any(axis=1)
        )

out = df_usage[mask]

Output:
  item_id  start_count  end_count  received_total
0   10346    100000000         10              19

Equality OP's method:
out.equals(df_too_many_consuables)
# True

Explanation

Select all columns to compare and apply df.gt on axis=0 to check if any value is larger than the mapped values for column 'item_id' (Series.map). Intermediate:

df_usage[['start_count', 'end_count', 'received_total']].gt(item_map, axis=0)

   start_count  end_count  received_total
0         True      False           False # True: 100000000 > 28644.99
1        False      False           False
2        False      False           False
3        False      False           False
4        False      False           False
5        False      False           False
6        False      False           False
7        False      False           False
8        False      False           False


Chain df.any to check row-wise (axis=1) for any True.
Use the resulting mask for boolean indexing.


Note that if a value from 'item_id' doesn't have a match in historical_orders_dict, it will get mapped as NaN. Since NaN values in pandas are considered to be neither greater than nor less than any other value, such an 'item_id' will never show up in out. If you do want such a value to show up, you can use Series.map + Series.fillna with some threshold, e.g. 0.
E.g., suppose we use:
historical_orders_dict = {
    '10346': 28644.99,
    'NOT_10877': 28979.99, # value 10877 absent
    '10695': 6200.0,
    '70020': 1960.0,
    '40265': 57300.0,
    '91524': 9750.0,
    '60022': 200.0,
    '10210': 156.0,
    '11040': 49350.0}

out with df_usage['item_id'].map(historical_orders_dict):
  item_id  start_count  end_count  received_total
0   10346    100000000         10              19

out with df_usage['item_id'].map(historical_orders_dict).fillna(0):
  item_id  start_count  end_count  received_total
0   10346    100000000         10              19
1   10877            2         11              20

